# Avoid repeatation of rows for every instance when joined with a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi i have 3 tables and i am trying to join them to get a desire table. I have tried group by and temp tables options to get the desired table but no help. I want to avoid duplicates for every instance of a value in one table from another table.

Table 1 Customer Table:

```
CstId          CstDetails       CstType    
----------  ---------------  ------------
    1           address 1         1
    2           address 2         1
    3           address 3         1
    4           address 4         2
    5           address 5         2
```

Table 2 Customer Relationship:

```
CstId            CstGroupId
----------   ----------------
    1               4 (this is same as CustomerId)
    2               5 (this is same as CustomerId)
    3               4 (this is same as CustomerId)
```

Table 3 Customer Notes:

```
CstId          NotesId     NoteTxt
-----------   ---------    ---------
    1            1           note11
    1            2           note12
    1            3           note13
    3            1           note31
    4            1           note41
    4            2           note42
    4            3           note43
    4            4           note44
    4            5           note45
```

Now i want the result to be in the below format

```
Table result:
                                    (NoteId)  (Notetxt)    (NoteId)         (Notetxt)
    CstId  CstDetails  CstGroupId  CstNoteId   CstNote   CstGroupNoteId   CstGroupNote
      1    address1       4         1          note11        1              note41
      1    address1       4         2          note12        2              note42
      1    address1       4         3          note13        3              note43
      1    address1       4         null       null          4              note44
      1    address1       4         null       null          5              note45
```

But i am getting CstGroupNote repeated for all the CstNote, which i am trying to avoid.

Is there a way i could achieve this result?

Below is the code i use:

```
select c.cstid, c.cstdetails, cn.cstnotesid, cn.cstnotetxt
insert into temp1
from customer c
    left outer join customernotes cn
        on c.cstid = cn.cstid
where c.customertypeid = 1

select cr.cstid, cr.cstgroupid, cn.cstgroupnoteid, cn.cstnotetxt
insert into temp2
from customerrelationship cr
    left outer join customernotes cn
        on cr.cstgroupid = cn.customerid

select t1.cstid, t1.cstdetails, t1.cstnotesid, t1.cstnotetxt, t2.cstgroupnoteid, t2.cstnotetext
from temp1 t1
    left outer join t2
        on t1.cstid = t2.cstid
```

Comment: What is the query you have so far?

Comment: I have created 2 temp tables one to get customernotes and second to get groupnotes and then i join both the temp tables with left outer join based on customerid

Comment: below is the code i used:                                               select c.cstid, c.cstdetails, cn.cstnotesid, cn.cstnotetxt
insert into temp1
from customer c
 left outer join customernotes cn
  on c.cstid = cn.cstid
where c.customertypeid = 1

select cr.cstid, cr.cstgroupid, cn.cstgroupnoteid, cn.cstnotetxt
insert into temp2
from customerrelationship cr
 left outer join customernotes cn
  on cr.cstgroupid = cn.customerid

select t1.cstid, t1.cstdetails, t1.cstnotesid, t1.cstnotetxt, t2.cstgroupnoteid, t2.cstnotetext
from temp1 t1
 left outer join t2
  on t1.cstid = t2.cstid

Comment: the tables that you provide as example are missing columns! in your query example their are more columns. we need the data of them in order to match it to your desired table that you provided

Comment: cstnoteid is alias for noteid  and cstnotetxt is alias for notetxt     same thing for cstgroupnoteid and cstgroupnotetxt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select CstId, 
       max(CstDetails) CstDetails, 
       max(CstGroupId) CstGroupId, 
       max(CstNoteId) CstNoteId, 
       max(CstNote) CstNote, 
       max(CstGroupNoteId) CstGroupNoteId, 
       max(CstGroupNote) CstGroupNote
from
(select c.CstId, 
        c.CstDetails,
        0 CstGroupId,
        n.NotesId CmbNotesId,
        n.NotesId CstNoteId,
        n.NoteTxt CstNote,
        0 CstGroupNoteId,
        '' CstGroupNote
 from customer c
 left outer join customernotes n on c.cstid = n.cstid
 where c.customertypeid = 1
 union all
 select c.CstId,
        c.CstDetails,
        r.CstGroupId,
        n.NotesId CmbNotesId,
        0 CstNoteId,
        '' CstNote,
        n.NotesId CstGroupNoteId,
        n.NoteTxt CstGroupNote
 from customer c
 left outer join customerrelationship r on c.cstid = r.cstid
 left outer join customernotes n on r.CstGroupId = n.cstid
 where c.customertypeid = 1) u
group by CstId, CmbNotesId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table and an outer join
The trick there is the
and cn.cstnotesid = cG.cstnotesid
to link those two on one row

```
select c.cstid, c.cstdetails, cn.cstnotesid, cn.cstnotetxt
      ,cG.CstGroupId, cG.cstnotesid, cG.cstnotetxt
from customer c
join customernotes cn
  on cn.cstid = c.cstid 
outer join  (select c.cstid, c.CstGroupId, cn.cstnotesid, cn.cstnotetxt
                from customer c
                join customernotes cn
                on cn.cstid = c.CstGroupId) as cG
        on c.cstid = cG.cstid
       and cn.cstnotesid = cG.cstnotesid
order by c.cstid, cn.cstnotesid, cG.cstnotesid
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution works only if the notesid matched, where as in my case its not true all the time.